# Longest path with color condition in tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I succeeded to solve this using "naive" solution checking for each node the longest path including this node but was told there is a better solution.

I am looking for help with how to solve this problem efficiently and how to approach similar problems (tips or thinking method will be appreciated)

Say I have a tree where each node is orange or white.
I need to write an algorithm to get the length of the longest "good" path

a "good" path is a path that starts at a white node, climbs up 0 or more white nodes and then go down 0 or more orange nodes

given the next tree as an example

[image: example picture]

the algorithm should return 4 because the longest path starts at 18 and ends with 15

Comment: So good path means whitenode->white parent(if it exists)-> longest path of only orange nodes on its sibling ?

Comment: @SomeDude yeah but keep in mind the root does not have to be white it can be longest path in the left subtree or in the right subtree, all you need is a path of whites with white parent and then orange path such that the total amount of nodes is maximized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with linear time complexity:

Traverse the tree in post order (depth first), and for each visited node, collect the size of the longest monochrome path downwards starting from that node -- so all nodes in that path should have the same color as the current node. Let's call this length the node's "monochrome height"

Additionally, if the current node is white, get the greatest monochrome height among its orange children. If the sum of the current (white) monochrome height and that orange height is greater than the maximum so far, then retain that sum as a maximised solution (best so far).

Here is some code in Python that implements that idea:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, colored=False, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.colored = colored
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def longestpath(root):
    maxlen = 0

    def monochromeheight(node):  # recursive function
        nonlocal maxlen  # this is the overall best result

        if node is None:  # base case
            return 0

        # First get the children's data
        leftheight = monochromeheight(node.left)
        rightheight = monochromeheight(node.right)

        # Then determine the monochrome height of this node
        currheight = 0
        if leftheight > 0 and node.left.colored == node.colored:
            currheight = leftheight
        if rightheight > currheight and node.right.colored == node.colored:
            currheight = rightheight
        currheight += 1

        # Check whether this is a white node with an orange child.
        #   If so, check if the white + orange path form a better solution
        if not node.colored:
            if  node.left and node.left.colored and currheight + leftheight > maxlen:
                maxlen = currheight + leftheight
            if node.right and node.right.colored and currheight + rightheight > maxlen:
                maxlen = currheight + rightheight

        return currheight

    monochromeheight(root)  # ignore returned value
    return maxlen
```

And then a demo run on the example tree:

```py
# Demo run on example tree
tree =  Node(20, False,
            Node(18, False,
                Node(32, True,
                    Node(70, False,
                        Node(80, False,
                        )
                    ),
                    Node(13, True,
                        Node(17, True)
                    )
                ),
                Node(22, True)
            ),
            Node(26, True,
                None,
                Node(15, True,
                    Node(30, False,
                        Node(40, False),
                        Node(25, True)
                    ),
                    Node(19, False)
                )
            )
        )

print(longestpath(tree))  # 4
```

Comment: can you please guide me how you think of this solution? the idea of calculating 1 thing in recursion (monochromatic height) is clear but how should i think of the idea of combining managing the max through the calculations

Comment: I would say this comes with practice. The more you solve these types of problems, and check how others have done it, the more you can rely on the ideas that pop up in your conscious mind.